# Best solution for tiling a geotiff?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, tiles, mbtiles

I have some GeoTIFF files that I want to bring into the web.

The spatial reference of these GeoTIFF files are multiple but are never WebMercator (EPSG:3857) and I need the web map to be in the same projection system than the original image.

So, I intend to use Leaflet with the [Proj4Leaflet](https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) plugin to set a custom projection.
Then, I need a software to generate tiles from a GeoTIFF in the same projection system than it.

Does anyone know what software could I use, knowing I have ArcGIS Desktop but not Server and I'm looking for a freeware solution?

Comment: tiff is quite big for web, png would load faster with no loss of quality https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#ImageFormats

Comment: Try gdal2tiles or MapTiler that is developed on top of gdal2tiles.

Comment: As MapTiler is not free for the size of my GeoTIFF files, I think gdal2tiles is a very good choice for this case. Thanks a lot for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use TileMill or MapBoxStudio or if you have lots of Maps/Charts in GeoTiff then MapTilerPro.

For ArcGIS for Desktop you can use Arc2Earth Extension to create Tiles.

Are you looking to create XYZ, TMS or MBTILES sqlite database?

For mobile app use mbtiles.

For web TMS, check out http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/ for nice map of zoom levels of tiles.